# How does Background Verification through NASSCOM work?

Tags: background-check, india

Recently I got an offer from a multinational corporation and they want me to register in the National Skills Registry (NSR) and I registered. My first company registered in 2011. I worked there from 2010 and I quit in 2012.  I am now worried this may be held against me

How is the NSR Verification done? If the verification fails, is there a standard process they follow?

Comment: Hey ram and welcome to [workplace.se]. Most of us do not know what MNC, NSR, or NASCOM is, or what you are actually asking as a result. Could you please [edit] your question to explain clearly what you are asking? Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to Google, MNC ["may refer to Media Nusantara Citra, Indonesian media company and owner of RCTI, MNC TV, Sun TV, and Indovision"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNC), NSR is the [National Swine Registry](http://www.nationalswine.com/) and [NASCOM is a company that makes magnetic switch gear.](http://www.nascominc.com/)  I frankly have no idea how an offer from an Indonesian media conglomerate would want you to register with the (American) national swine registry, or what either of those things have to do with magnetic security devices.

Comment: MNC would likely be Multi-National Corporation though the other acronyms I don't know so it would be useful to explain them and possibly consider links so we could understand the situation here as it isn't clear where in the world is this question coming?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do background checks verify employment?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/35272/how-do-background-checks-verify-employment)

Comment: He's asking a specific question about NSR which the alleged duplicate doesn't address in the least.

Comment: NASSCOM is the national governing body and NSR is the National skills registry a database of knowledge professionals, with there background details like education, employment. Once employee registers there experience data in NSR and either employee or employer can request for background verification. And the verification results will be permanently available in NSR rest of your life.\

Answer (score 8):

I think it may be best to do some reading up on this [website](http://www.techgoss.com/Story/25S12-NASSCOM---nbsp--Rs-2000-To-Double-Check-IT-BPO-Background.aspx) which will give you a overview of how it works and the practises it follows.

In short NASSCOM is a Database that stores records for all IT and BPO employees in India. Your potential Employer pays a figure to a NASSCOM Certified Background Checker who will check your professional employment history. And report back on the findings.

If your verification fails then it is entirley dependant on the company. I would advise having a look at the following [site](http://www.shrmindia.org/knowledge-center/talent-acquisition/background-investigations/background-checks-india) where you can see that "*Infosys asking about 100 employees to leave due to discrepancies in their resumes*". And that a "*senior professional, boasting certificates from IIT Mumbai and IIM Ahmedabad and 20 years of corporate experience, being on the verge of receiving a job offer when background investigations revealed that the certificates from IIT and IIM were fake*".

Comment: Both links are broken now.