# How do background checks verify employment?

Tags: hiring-process, applications, background-check

I heard  companies usually outsource background checks to other companies. I also heard that background checks verify criminal history, education and employment.

I know you can find criminal records by browsing a public database but I don't think there's a database that tells where people worked.

Is the Employment Check of a background check simply them calling the company you listed on your resume? Calling the phone number you listed on your job application?

Comment: Hi, I edited this slightly to make it more appropriately on topic. If I changed your intent too much let me know or [edit] it, welcome to The Workplace!

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/35272/edit) and add a country tag.

Answer (score 7):

I just started at a new company this last summer and they used a third party company to do a background check.

They ask for the name and city of the job, and the dates you worked there. They will then look up the number for the company online and call them and ask to speak to HR and will verify the information you gave. If they can not find a phone number, they will contact you asking for some contact information. If it can't be provided, you will need to provide pay stubs or tax forms.

I had to go through that with one of my jobs as it was a start up that had gone under and I didn't have the contact information of anyone who had worked there any more.